# server path, minus the current folder

Tags: php, path

Alright.

Think I am doing this far too complicated and there is an easier solution. I need to get the current server path $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; minus the current folder.

```
$full_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$current_folder = strrchr( $full_path, '/' ); 
$strlength = strlen( $current_folder ) - 1;
$pathlength = strlen( $full_path );
$newlength = $pathlength - $strlength;
$newpath = substr( $full_path, 0, $newlength );
```

This code works, but I think it might be overkill.

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function realpath and go one folder higher by adding /../:

```
$newpath = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/../");
```

Answer (score 3):

`dirname()` is very handy for this.
dunno what path you're asking for though, gonna give you both:

```
$above_root    = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/";
$above_current = dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do something like this? It's not really pretty, but as far as I know you can just append `..` to a path.

```
$parent =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../';
```

You might want to check if  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` has the directory separator in the end, and if you need to add it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

PHP offers all kind of functions when working with paths and filesystem: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$dirs = explode('\\', $path);
$pathWithoutDir = array_slice($dirs, 0, count($dirs) - 1);
```

I guess that dirty code aboive will work. You can also change `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to `__DIR__` which is equal to `dirname(__FILE__)`.

EDIT: Code updated.

Comment: @up Thanks! It was written here.

Comment: dirname(__FILE__) !== $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Answer (score 0):

$newpath = preg_replace("/[^\/]+$/", "", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

Comment: RegeX for splitting path? It isn't best solution, don't ya think?

Comment: If I'm matching text I use regexp: I find it easier to use than mucking about with substring matching, and in most contexts the performance penalty is ignorable. I appreciate that others may not agree with me.